# / partition without "root" flag in GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, root

I'm curious in one thing: when I downloaded GParted and looked at my root partition it was without "root" flag, and when I tried to flag it there was no "root" flag from the list. When I was installing Ubuntu (Ubuntu Studio) I flagged the partition as "root".
Is it fine? As I understood, user just can't see the "root" flag of the root (/) partition even though it's flagged.
Am I right? If not, will it cause any issues while installing apps, packages or in general any problems?

Comment: I've never heard about a `"root" flag`, I think you missunderstand something. Did you install using the `something else`-option where you have to choose (or create) a partition as the OS-partition which will be mounted at `/` which is the so called `root partition`.

Comment: Yeah, I performed manual installation. I didn't use GParted to create all the partition, but I just wonder if it's fine that there is no "root" flag, because while creating partitions under the "Flags" I chose "root" for my / partition. Is it fine, that I've tried to change flags on my root partition? I didn't choose anything there, but I still some kind of scared of something being installed in the wrong location because of the package manager not knowing where is the root partition. Probably I'm overthinking, but still, is it fine?

Comment: Just the fact that I chose "Manage Flags" in Gparted makes me think that I broke some script and now I will lose my information and security etc.

Comment: Don't worry, just choosing `Manage Flags` will not change anything. In Gparted you'd always have to click the `Apply`-button to apply the chosen changes to your partitions. If you didn't choose any new flag, the `Apply`-button will not even be activated. Your OS-partition doesn't need any flags, you're good to enjoy your new installation.

Comment: Thank you! When I changed an EFI partition flags I didn't need to click the Apply button and everything was saved, but anyway, I didn't change in root partition anything so everything should be good. I just always think like, for example, "if I click here and it has something to do with system so there can be an issue that something is going to be broken even though I didn't change anything" etc. Thank you again! Wish you alll the best!

Comment: it is late 1 year, lol. i have the same problem, from article that i found at https://www.linux.org/threads/gparted-partition-and-filesystem-flags.11640/. Flags indicate that a certain property, characteristic, or feature is active or is present. Flags can either be on or off. If the flag is not seen, then it is off or inactive/non-existent. Certain flags are only supported on particular filesystems and partitioning tables. so when you set root partition flags to root, maybe it is not supported by partitioning tables. in my case, my drive implement GPT partition, root flags is only supported m